# error: the timestamp signature and/or certificate could not be verified or is malformed

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 a while back then uninstalled it because I needed space and a few months later when I tried to reinstall I got this error for SQL database tools and the other SQL packages that come with Visual Studio 2013, error is "`the timestamp signature and/or certificate could not be verified or is malformed`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found a solution to my problem. The error is caused be an SHA256 ceritificate thats in the build and the certificate expires on 10/6/2013 therefore when installing Visual Studio 2013 in present day it presents that error. The work around i used was to set the clock on my laptop before that date and then install Visual studio 2013 and the workaround was successful. Credit does not go to me, i only obtain this information from the following web page:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/10/08/known-issue-ssdt-install-fails-validating-certificates.aspx

credit goes to Jill McClenahan the individual that posted the solution. Forgive me explaination i am a newbie.

Comment: Hi, I work on the SSDT team and we've been trying to reproduce issues similar to yours for a while. When you say you reinstalled Visual Studio 2013 where exactly did you reinstall it from? We keep trying different ways to uninstall and then reinstall VS2013 but are not having any luck in running into this issue. If you have a solid set of steps that might help us verify that we have it fixed. Thanks!

Comment: To answer your question, I got this with the DreamSpark Visual Studio Professional 2013 with Update 2 installing on Windows 7 SP1 Pro x64. I have VS 2010 Pro currently installed. I get it for MS SQL Server 2012 Native Client, MS SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL SciptDom, Prerequisites for SDDT, MS System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012 (+x64), MS SQL Server 2012 Management Objects (+x64), Workflow Manager Tools 1.0 for Visual Studio, and Microsoft Report Viewer Add-On for Visual Studio 2013. Additionally I get a bunch of "A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority".

Comment: @KevinCunnane Forgot to mention your username so you would get a mention.

Comment: Sir, the link does not work. The post is removed.